# ¿Como obtener valores de un modelo y almacenarlos en otro modelo?

Tags: django

en mi proyecto de django tengo dos aplicaciones, registros y usuarios, en registros tengo varios modelos que tienen atributos en común (provincia, municipio y sclinico), esas mismas variabes las tengo en el modelo perfil que se encuentra en usuarios, lo que quiero hacer es tomar los valores de esas variables en perfil y pasarselos a los modelos que tengo en registrosº, aqui les comparto el código, si pueden ayudarme se los agradeceré muchísimo,

```
# Modelo Perfil de la app usuarios
class Perfil(models.Model):
    cprov = (('LH', 'La Habana'), ('CIE', 'Cienfuegos'), ('VC', 'Villa Clara'), ('SC', 'Santiago de cuba'))

    cmunic = (('SA', 'Santa Clara'), ('CA', 'Camajuaní'), ('RE', 'Remedios'), ('CI', 'Caibarien'),
              ('SC', 'Santiago de Cuba'))

    csitio = (('IN', 'Infanti Norte'), ('IS', 'Infantil Sur'), ('CJ', 'Pol. Carlos J Finlay'),
              ('CT', 'Pol. Camilo Torres'), ('LP', 'Pol. López Peña'), ('28', 'Pol. 28 de Septiembre'),
              ('30', 'Pol 30 de Noviembre'), ('JJ', 'Pol. José Martí'), ('JP', 'Pol. Josué País'), ('LS', 'CPHEM SC'),
              ('ES', 'EMCOMED Santiago de Cuba'), ('LO', 'Laboratorio Oriente'), ('LF', 'Lab. Inmunología Clínica IFV'),
              ('JL', 'HPP José Luis Miranda'), ('SA', 'Pol. Santa Clara'), ('JR', 'Pol. José Ramón Acosta'),
              ('MA', 'Pol. Marta Abreu'), ('XX', 'Pol XX Aniversario'), ('CR', 'Pol Capitán Roberto Fleites'),
              ('CH', 'Pol. Chiqui Gómez Lubián'), ('LV', 'CPHEM VC'), ('EV', 'EMCOMED Villa Clara'),
              ('OC', 'Pol. Octavio de la Concepción y Pedraja'), ('MF', 'Pol. Manuel Fajardo Rivero'),
              ('HM', 'HMGD 26 de Diciembre'), ('XA', 'Pol. XXX Aniversario'), ('CC', 'Pol. Camilo Cienfuegos'),
              ('LF', 'Pol. Leandro Figueroa'), ('PA', 'Pol. Pablo Aguero'))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    provincia = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, choices=cprov)
    municipio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, choices=cmunic)
    sclinico = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, choices=csitio)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='perfil_pics')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Perfil'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

# Modelo Incluido de la app registros

class Incluido(models.Model):
    sino = (('1', 'Sí'), ('2', 'No'))
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    sclinico = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    numero = models.IntegerField("No.")
    iniciales = models.CharField("Iniciales del sujeto", max_length=10)
    feceva = models.DateField("Fecha de evaluación")
    inclusion = models.CharField("¿El sujeto se incluyo?", max_length=2, choices=sino)
    fecinc = models.DateField("Fecha de Inclusión", null=True, blank=True)
    codigo = models.CharField("Codigo del sujeto", max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    causano = models.IntegerField("Si no incluido refiera número de causa")
    investigador = models.CharField("Investigador", max_length=100)
    firma = models.CharField("Firma", max_length=2, choices=sino)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inc_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefinir el metodo save en mi modelo Incluido, me sirvió ademas para filtar por sitio clínico, y así solamente mostrar los datos a los usuarios del mismo sitio.

```py
# mi models.py

class Incluido(models.Model):
    sino = (('1', 'Sí'), ('2', 'No'))
    provincia = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    municipio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sclinico = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    numero = models.IntegerField("No.")
    iniciales = models.CharField("Iniciales del sujeto", max_length=10)
    feceva = models.DateField("Fecha de evaluación")
    inclusion = models.CharField("¿El sujeto se incluyo?", max_length=2, choices=sino)
    fecinc = models.DateField("Fecha de Inclusión", null=True, blank=True)
    codigo = models.CharField("Codigo del sujeto", max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    causano = models.IntegerField("Si no incluido refiera número de causa")
    investigador = models.CharField("Investigador", max_length=100)
    firma = models.CharField("Firma", max_length=2, choices=sino)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.provincia = Perfil.history.values()[0]['provincia']
        self.municipio = Perfil.history.values()[0]['municipio']
        self.sclinico = Perfil.history.values()[0]['sclinico']
        super(Incluido, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inc_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

# mi vista

class IncView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Incluido
    template_name = 'registros/incluido_show.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IncView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        qry = Incluido.objects.filter(sclinico=Perfil.history.values()[0]['sclinico'])
        context['datos'] = qry

        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Según veo puedes hacer dos cosas:

1. Copiar todas las variables de selección que necesitas del modelo `Perfil` al modelo `Incluido`, pero seria duplicación de código.
2. Lo otro es crear un archivo llamado `choices.py`, y copiar en ese archivo todas las variables. Para usarlas el modelo que desees deberás importar el archivo `choices` en casa modelo. Dependiendo donde lo importes deberás agregar las ruta completa. Por ejemplo sí `choices` esta en la aplicación `usuarios` arriba de tu archivo `models.py` basta que escribas `from .choices import *`

Ya que el `.` simboliza el directorio actual. Pero sí estas en archivo `models.py` de aplicación `registros`. Debes escribir:

```
from usuarios.choices import *
```

Comment: Gracias por tratar de ayudarme mihael, pero como mi objetivo es evitar como bien dices la duplicación de código y hacerles la vida más facil a mis usuarios, hice esto, lo comparto por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, y me dió resultado, redefiní el metodo save en mi modelo Incluido ```python     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.provincia = Perfil.history.values()[0]['provincia']
        self.municipio = Perfil.history.values()[0]['municipio']
        self.sclinico = Perfil.history.values()[0]['sclinico']
        super(Incluido, self).save(*args, **kwargs)```